# VueJS element populated callback

Tags: vue.js, callback

Does vue have a callback when the element finishes getting populated?  I have an ajax call that returns a 3-tier tree, and if the top level tree only returns one I want to expand everything.  It's working somewhat, but only the first 6 rows get expanded.

```
myVue.results = data.results;
$('#vueContainer').find('.expand').css({ display: 'block' });
```

I have successfully used the following, but would rather use a callback for obvious reasons...

```
setTimeout(function() {
    myVue.results = data.results;
    $('#vueContainer').find('.expand').css({ display: 'block' });
}, 100);
```

Comment: why not use `vue` instead of `jquery` to show/hide?

Comment: I'm only 2 months in on taking over this project and it's extremely JQuery heavy.  None of it's OOP and the previous dev is still working on it as well so the transition has to be slower.  It's mostly written as: content = '<div>'; content += '<div class="header">; ... $('#main_container').html('content');  Ya know, that kinda coding style...  Baby steps lol

Comment: you can try this https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated

Comment: I was able to make it work with updated hook, thank you.  If I had known they called them hooks instead of callbacks that would have helped.  "I wrote you this big sexy hook, I think you're gonna really dig it." --Michael Bolton